# Strange symbols being printed in string C

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming, but what I'm trying to do is create a BST using arrays. Here is my code for the headers that I am using:

bst.h

```
#ifndef ASSIGNMENT4_BST_H
#define ASSIGNMENT4_BST_H

// ====== this is in bst.h
#include "data.h"
typedef struct {Node *tree_nodes; unsigned char *is_free; int size;} BStree_struct;
typedef BStree_struct* BStree;
BStree bstree_ini(int size);
void bstree_insert(BStree bst, Key *key, int data);
void bstree_traversal(BStree bst);
void bstree_free(BStree bst);

#endif //ASSIGNMENT4_BST_H
```

data.h

```
#ifndef ASSIGNMENT4_DATA_H
#define ASSIGNMENT4_DATA_H

typedef struct {char *name; int id;} Key;
typedef struct {Key *key; int data;} Node;
Key *key_construct(char *in_name, int in_id);
int key_comp(Key key1, Key key2);
void print_key(Key *key);
void print_node(Node node);

#endif //ASSIGNMENT4_DATA_H
```

And here is the code for my actual source files:

bst.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "bst.h"
// Input: ’size’: size of an array
// Output: a pointer of type BStree,
// i.e. a pointer to an allocated memory of BStree_struct type
// Effect: dynamically allocate memory of type BStree_struct
// allocate memory for a Node array of size+1 for member tree_nodes
// allocate memory for an unsigned char array of size+1 for member is_free
// set all entries of is_free to 1
// set member size to ’size’;

void bstree_insert_helper (BStree, Key *, int, int);

BStree bstree_ini(int size) {
    BStree bstree = (BStree*) malloc(sizeof(BStree));
    bstree->tree_nodes = (Node*) malloc(size+1 * sizeof(Node));
    bstree->is_free = (unsigned char *) malloc (size+1 * sizeof(unsigned char));
    memset (bstree->is_free, '1', size+1);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size; i++){
//        printf("%c", bstree->is_free[i]);
    }
    return bstree;
}

// Input: ’bst’: a binary search tree
// ’key’: a pointer to Key
// ’data’: an integer
// Effect: ’data’ with ’key’ is inserted into ’bst’
// if ’key’ is already in ’bst’, do nothing
void bstree_insert(BStree bst, Key *key, int data) {
    bstree_insert_helper(bst, key, data, 1);
}

void bstree_insert_helper (BStree bst, Key *key, int data, int index){
    if (bst->is_free[index] == '1'){
        bst->tree_nodes[index].key = key;
        bst->tree_nodes[index].data = data;
        bst->is_free[index] = '0';
    } else {
        int value = key_comp(*key, *bst->tree_nodes[index].key);
        if (value < 0){
            int newIndex = 2*index;
            if (bst->is_free[newIndex] == '1'){
                bst->tree_nodes[newIndex].key = key;
                bst->tree_nodes[newIndex].data = data;
                bst->is_free[newIndex] = '0';
            } else {
                bstree_insert_helper(bst, key, data, newIndex);
            }
        } else if (value > 0){
            int newIndex = 2*index+1;
            if (bst->is_free[newIndex] == '1'){
                bst->tree_nodes[newIndex].key = key;
                bst->tree_nodes[newIndex].data = data;
                bst->is_free[newIndex] = '0';
            } else {
                bstree_insert_helper(bst, key, data, newIndex);
            }
        } else {
            puts("Key already exists... Aborting");
        }
    }
}

int main (){
    BStree bsTree = bstree_ini(10);
    bstree_insert_helper(bsTree, key_construct("Ilya", 1), 11, 1);
    bstree_insert_helper(bsTree, key_construct("Covin", 2), 12, 1);
    bstree_insert_helper(bsTree, key_construct("adolf", 3), 13, 1);
    bstree_insert_helper(bsTree, key_construct("henlo", 4), 14, 1);
    print_node(bsTree->tree_nodes[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

data.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "data.h"


// Input: ’in_name’: a string ends with ’\0’
// ’in_id’: an integer
// Output: a pointer of type pointer to Key,
// pointing to an allocated memory containing a Key
// Effect: dynamically allocate memory to hold a Key
// set Key’s id to be in_id
// dynamically allocate memory for the Key’s name
// so that name will contain what is in ’in_name’.
// Note: may use strdup()
Key *key_construct(char *in_name, int in_id) {
    Key *key = (Key*) malloc(sizeof(Key));
    key->name = strdup(in_name);
    key->id = in_id;
    return key;
}
// Input: ’key1’ and ’key2’ are two Keys
// Output: if return value < 0, then key1 < key2,
// if return value = 0, then key1 = key2,
// if return value > 0, then key1 > key2,
// Note: use strcmp() to compare key1.name and key2.name
// if key1.name = key2.name, then compare key1.id with key2.id
int key_comp(Key key1, Key key2) {
    int value = strcmp(key1.name, key2.name);
    if (value < 0 || value > 0){
        return value;
    } else {
        if (key1.id < key2.id){
            return -1;
        }else if (key1.id > key2.id){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

// Input: ’key’: a pointer to Key
// Effect: ( key->name key->id ) is printed
void print_key(Key *key) {
    char *name = key->name;
    int id = key->id;

    printf("%s, %i", name, id);
}

// Input: ’node’: a node
// Effect: node.key is printed and then the node.data is printed
void print_node(Node node) {
    printf("%s, %d \n", node.key->name, node.data);
}
```

The issue is that when I run the print_node function in main in bst.c, I expect it to print the key.name and data for indices 1,2,3, and 7 in the array properly. However, the key.name for indices 1 and 3 are not printed properly. Instead, I get a bunch of gibberish that looks something like this - `0+@]�, 11` if I used `print_node(bsTree->tree_nodes[1])`. I have a feeling it has something to do with me incorrectly allocating memory for the keys in data.c but I cannot figure out exactly what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error is here:

```
(size+1 * sizeof(Node))
```

inside `BStree bstree_ini(int size)`:

```
bstree->tree_nodes = (Node*) malloc(size+1 * sizeof(Node));
bstree->is_free = (unsigned char *) malloc (size+1 * sizeof(unsigned char));
memset (bstree->is_free, '1', size+1);
```

`*` is executed first, then `+` (like in normal math), see [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the expression:

```
size+1 * sizeof(Node)
```

is equal to:

```
size + (1 * sizeof(Node))
```

which is not what you wanted!

Use proper braces:

```
malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(Node));
```

or use `calloc`:

```
calloc(sizeof(Node), size + 1);
```

Some friendly notices:

- Nice code!
- Please [don't cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).
- `bstree->is_free` would be clearer if it would be `bool` type. And it would be clearer (to me) if it would be `bstree->is_used` as I can expect it is initialized to zero on a new object, it would be also easy to clear it `memset(bstree->is_used, 0, ...)`. You just assign `'1'` and `'0'` to it, I find boolean to be clearer for this indent, `bstree->us_used[obj_num] = true;` In the future you may go for a bit-container.